# API Platform: How to add Filters inside an operation?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

It seems it’s possible to define filters on an operation level, yet documentation seems sparse on this. I want to define a unique set of filters per operation.
Meaning there is a getCollection operation with a custom controller, no filters.
But I also want the standard getCollection operation but with filters.

I got the 2 operations working but I can't seem to figure out what needs to go into the named argument filters of type array.

I already tried the following:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    description: 'The Audits keep track of actions performed by users or the system.',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            security: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
            securityMessage: 'Only admins can access all audits freely',
            filters: [
                new ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties: ['type']),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['audit:full', 'base:full', 'user:basic']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['audit:full', 'base:full', 'user:basic']],
)]
class Audit {
```

But sadly this gives me an error:

```
ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactory::getFilter(): Argument #1 ($filterId) must be of type string, ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter given, called in /app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/OpenApi/Factory/OpenApiFactory.php on line 451
```

I also tried adding the OrderFilter directly but that also fails:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    description: 'The Audits keep track of actions performed by users or the system.',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(
            security: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
            securityMessage: 'Only admins can access all audits freely',
            filters: [
                new OrderFilter(properties: ['type']),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['audit:full', 'base:full', 'user:basic']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['audit:full', 'base:full', 'user:basic']],
)]
class Audit {
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I missed a bit of documentation at https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/

It seems you can add filters with the following:

```
GetCollection(
    uriTemplate: '/other-operation',
    filters: [
        'book.date_filter'
    ],
    provider: BookProvider::class
)
```

And then you need to add that in your services:

```
 book.date_filter:
    parent: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.date_filter'
    arguments: [ { publicationDate: ~ } ]
    tags:  [ 'api_platform.filter' ]
```